# Openssl dnQualifier hash

Tags: ssl, openssl, php-openssl

Well, i decided that i have to post this question because, seriously, i couldn´t find anything related to it.

I´m creating a self-sign certificate but, this is based on another one that has certain properties and at certain point, the below happens and i need to understand what is it and why:

```
Issuer: O=example.com, OU=example.com CN=.cc-admin/dnQualifier=1sfCakNi3x6UPCYmogMrITuPMos=
```

....

```
Subject: O=example.com, OU=example.com, CN=SM.ws-1/dnQualifier=H/z8HyVtKEZSFoTeeI2UV9aBaq8=
```

....

```
X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 21
 keyid:the keyid
 DirName:/O=example.com/OU=example.com/CN=.ra-1b/dnQualifier=4NMh-Nx9WhmbDcXKl1puOjX4lsp=
 serial:56:CE
```

**What is that hash after de dnQualifier? and why is it always different?**

That´s it!, that´s all i need to understand. Thanks for you time, regards

Comment: dnQualifier has no standard semantics and I've never seen it used, so I have no idea what the values are in your cert. They do appear to be base64 of 20-byte values, which could be a hash, except that the third one is not validly encoded -- did you change it? In any case, the three entities named by Subject, Issuer, and AKI.DirName are different entities, with different CommonName values, so if the unknown dnQualifier is somehow related to the entity, which it should be, it makes sense for the values to be different.

Comment: Hello Dave, thank you for answering. I´m using a manual and building after the instructions on it, and you are right!!, it is base64 encoded. The manual says: "Verify that there is exactly one DnQualifier present in the Subject field and that
the DnQualifier value is the Base64 encoded thumbprint of the subject public key in
the certificate. Also verify that there is exactly one
DnQualifier present in the Issuer field and that the DnQualifier value is the Base64
encoded thumbprint the issuer's public key."... How do i get the issuer´s public key?

Comment: Look in the issuer's certificate, i.e. the certificate whose subject name is the same as the issuer name in this certificate.